# Django website with dynamic side navigation menu

Tags: django

Can someone please advise if it is posaible to build a website using django that has a dynamic menu that can be managed from the admin area? I want to be able to add menu items with urls that it should render when selected.

If yes, Can you please share some insights interms of what libraries can be used with some samples.

This seems to be challenging one but I am hoping that there might some super expert who might have cracked a solution for this requirement.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend waigtail https://wagtail.io/
It gives you a nice cms style admin i use it for my websites sidebar